# Error "The name does not exist in the current context", Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the function OnTriggerEnter2D I faced the error: "The name "collision" does not exist in the current context". Here is my code:

```
public int iLevelToLoad;
public string sLevelToLoad;

public bool useIntegerToLoadLevel = false;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collison)
{
    GameObject collisionGameObject = collision.gameObject;

    if(collisionGameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        LoadScene();
    }

}

void LoadScene ()
{
    if (useIntegerToLoadLevel)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(iLevelToLoad);
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sLevelToLoad);
    }
}
```

Comment: These types of issues are usually quickly noticeable within IDE's with a red squiggly identifier but the message provided gives enough context as to what the problem is. The variable name that you're trying to use does not exist as it is spelt; try to look where the error is occurring and making sure the name you're using is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

You pass as the parameter of `OnTriggerEnter2D()` function variable `collison`, but in function you trying to call `collision`. It is just a misprint. Change the parameter name as `collision`.

Comment: im sorry but how can i change it? ;-; im just a beginner and i would be thankful if u write down that script (i understood very less of this since i just started coding)

Comment: Replace this part of code: private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collison) to this: private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)

Comment: wait arent those are the same? ;-;

Comment: No, if you look careful

Comment: You are missing an ‘i’ in your collison. Here collis »_« on. To collis »i« on.

Comment: haha omg im so stupid ngl, anyway thank you for helping me fix this specific, im so dumb

Comment: Not at all. Admit the answer and close the question please